# Finding the two largest element of an array

Tags: arrays

For [Problem](http://codeforces.com/contest/659/problem/B):

> Finding and printing unique team of two students (otherwise printing "?") from each region out of n regions based on greater scores (from 0 to 800)

I thought that we can keep track of the largest and second largest element, initialized with scores of -1 and -1. There are only a few possibilities:

- If score is more than the largest, then largest must be the current and shift largest to second largest, but if largest is same as second largest, the team can be formed in two ways, hence undefined.
- Else if score is more than second then directly replace him.
- Else if score is same as second then also undefined

But it seems this is wrong, but I don't know why?

Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class B659 {
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = num();
    int m = num();
    String[] rgn1 = new String[m]; // students with highest score in their region
    String[] rgn2 = new String[m]; // students with second-highest score in their region
    int[] rgn1s = new int[m]; // highest score in the regions
    int[] rgn2s = new int[m]; // second-highest score in the regions
    Arrays.fill(rgn1s, -1);
    Arrays.fill(rgn2s, -1);
    boolean[] und = new boolean[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String sn = str();
        int r = num() - 1;
        int sc = num();
        if (sc > rgn1s[r]) {
        if (rgn2s[r] == rgn1s[r] && rgn1s[r] != -1) {
            und[r] = true;
            continue;
        } else {
            rgn2s[r] = rgn1s[r];
            rgn2[r] = rgn1[r];
        }
        rgn1s[r] = sc;
        rgn1[r] = sn;
        } else if (sc > rgn2s[r]) {
        rgn2s[r] = sc;
        rgn2[r] = sn;
        } else if (sc == rgn2s[r]) {
        und[r] = true;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        print((!und[i]) ? (rgn1[i] + " " + rgn2[i]) : "?");
    }
    }

    private static int num() {
    return sc.nextInt();
    }

    private static String str() {
    return sc.next();
    }

    private static void print(Object x) {
    System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just sort it and take the two off the end. If your prof says it's not efficient, tell him premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I know, but that is O(nlogn) and this is O(n). We go in a single pass and compare 3-5 times

Comment: @EdPlunkett actually you have a point

Comment: He may tell you that abuse of that adage is the root of a fair amount of evil too, and he won't be entirely wrong. But seriously though, I hate to say it but the point of the exercise is probably to demonstrate that you can do it the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't handle the situation when once the duplicate values has been encountered and the `und[r]` field has been set true, two higher values are encountered.

> For eg:
>   6 2
>   Ram 1 200
>   Shyam 1 200
>   Raju 2 200
>   Rita 1 300
>   Hera 2 500
>   Sita 1 500

You need to redefine the if and add another else if part for the duplicate entries if they happens to be the last pair.

```
else if (sc == rgn1s[r]) {
        und[r] = true;
        }
```

> For eg:
>   6 2
>   Ram 1 200
>   Shyam 1 300
>   Raju 2 200
>   Rita 1 500
>   Hera 2 500
>   Sita 1 500